# How to reload browser page by just appending a hash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

For example, when I am on `http://www.example.com/foo` and I use this:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/foo#bar";
```

The default action is that the page doesn't reload, and it just moves me over to the element with `id="bar"`.

But what if I explicitly want the page to refresh? How would I do that?

I can use jQuery if necessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reload the page just after changing the location. Like this:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/foo#bar";
location.reload();
```